# Unable to download file (Web Scraping) - OSError [Errorno22] - invalid argument

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, filepath, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I wrote a program in Python 3 which scrapes and download the pages of wikipedia category with certain depth and places them in a directory.

The problem which I am facing is, "suppose during the execution of code, if the algorithm encounters any page of wikipedia having special character like (*, #, $ etc.), then the algorithm fails with the below mentioned message in terms of error trace ".

An example of the special character wiki page is as follows:
`https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eden*`

The error trace is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\Pen Drive 8 GB\PDF\Code\wiki.py", line 103, in <module>
d.search_and_store("Biomedical_engineering", subcategory_depth=2, path=PATH)
File "F:\Pen Drive 8 GB\PDF\Code\wiki.py", line 98, in search_and_store
self.search_and_store(subcat_result['title'], subcategory_depth-1, path)
File "F:\Pen Drive 8 GB\PDF\Code\wiki.py", line 98, in search_and_store
self.search_and_store(subcat_result['title'], subcategory_depth-1, path)
File "F:\Pen Drive 8 GB\PDF\Code\wiki.py", line 76, in search_and_store
if self.write_page_text(path, page_result):
File "F:\Pen Drive 8 GB\PDF\Code\wiki.py", line 44, in write_page_text
txt_file = open(file_path, 'w')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'F:\\Code\\Wikipedia\\DATASETS\\Biomedical Engineering/Eden*.txt'
```

As you can see clearly, the algorithm scrapes the data of the pages without having any special character's, but why it raising the aforementioned error.

The MWE is very large. If anybody suggests, then I can share the same.

Please suggest something, as I am trying this since long and frustrated. I don't even have idea what I am doing wrong? Please help.

Any small help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You're using slashes in path along with backslashes. Try `txt_file = open(file_path.replace('/', '\\'), 'w')` or use `os.path.join()` to create path

Comment: I am using os.path.join() to create path!

Comment: Share code for creating path

Comment: Sure. I am sharing. Please check the recent edit after a few minutes!

Comment: Please see my edit @ Andersson!

Comment: I guess this is your problem `file_path = dir + "/" + page['title'].replace('/', '') + '.txt'`. Try `file_path = os.path.join(dir, (page['title'].rstrip('/') + '.txt'))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183015/discussion-between-m-s-and-andersson).